# How to retrive data from map object in spring core module

Tags: spring

```
package info.map;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MapDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext container=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springMap.xml");
    StudentMap sm=container.getBean("smap",StudentMap.class);
    HashMap hs=sm.getSno();
    Iterator i=hs.iterator();
    System.out.println(i);

    }

}
```

The above code shows an error which says:

> "The method iterator() is undefined for the type HashMap"

Comment: Show your SpringMap.xml file

Answer (score 0):

That because iterator method is not defined in [hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) directly. You could iterate on key or values or entry (key value pair)

You could do something like:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Iterator<String> keyIterator = map.keySet().iterator();//iterate over keys and while iterating you could say map.get(keyIterator.next())
Iterator<String> valueIterator = map.values().iterator();//iterate over values
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();//iterate over key value pair and you could do Map.Entry<String, String> entry = i.next(); entry.getKey() or entry.getValue()
```